# Nativescript installer won't install above 4.1.2

Tags: nativescript

If I run `npm uninstall -g nativescript` and then `npm install -g nativescript` it installs 4.1.2 and not the latest version 5.4.2.

I've tried to upgrade my nativescript by re-installing, but it still won't upgrade, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Strange, did you try specifying the version, like `npm install -g nativescript@latest` or `npm install -g nativescript@5.4.2`

Comment: I did. It appears to install, but then I check and the version is 4.1.2

Comment: If you mention the version in your command, it should either fail Or install the correct module version. NPM would never install a different version in this case.

Comment: You would think. What is the proper version of npm to be running? I tried to start over, but I'm getting Support for Node.js 12.4.0 is not verified. NativeScript CLI might not install or run properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get 4.1.2 when executing `npm install -g nativescript`.

Most probably you just have more than one `nativescript` CLI installed on your machine. You can figure it out by executing:

```
`which tns` (or `where tns` on Windows) - it will return the problematic `tns` 4.1.2. location.
`npm get prefix` - this is the location of your global npm modules where will be your nativescript@5.4.2.
`echo $PATH` - I suppose that the problematic `tns` location will be before the global npm modules location in your `PATH` variable.
```

In order to start using the 5.4.2 CLI, you just have to fix your $PATH value and set the global npm modules location before the NativeScript 4.1.2 one.

Answer (score 0):

It was nvm. I updated to node 12, but Nativescript was not compatible. Sidekick was really weird. It kept trying to install the cli but couldn’t. I switched back to the wrong nvm and it had 4.1.2 installed. My bad all the way around. It appears Sidekick picks the newest nvm version rather than the one you’ve selected to run. Once I uninstalled node 12 it reverted back to the proper version.